# Speech API Google Languages List?

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition, chromium, speech

I've developed an app that uses the Google Speech API.

But I can't find the languages list that it can recognize.

I've been googling but I can't find info about.

Anyone knows a link?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google voice search api support these language --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Voice_Search

Also you can check which languages are actually supported by going your android phone's `Settings>voice input & output settings > voice recognizer settings`